# Toggle button goes right after clicked?

Tags: bootstrap-4

In bootstrap,I included navigation bar toggle button on small screens.But when clicked,it changes position to right.I searched differnet videos or tutorials but none of them helped.

**Html:**

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Internet</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">TV</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Wireless</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link about" href="#">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="button">
                                <button>GET A QUOTE</button>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
header div.other-info .navbar-toggler{
    padding:3px 6px;
    margin-left:155%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a completed working example of your code?

Comment: I can give complete code